# jquery bind second ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax request which is showing data on success.
AFTER this is done, I'd like to do something else, the problem is that I can not 
touch the ajax code. I could have just done:

`$.ajax().success(bla).` But I can't touch this code.

I'd have to bind the second function somewhere else and make sure it comes after the first onsuccess. Can it be done?

is there maybe a global event AFTER the success event that I can use?

Comment: Nope, not without a referrence to the ajax function. There are global ajax events, but that would fire on any other ajax request as well. Maybe you can filter for something in a global ajax event ?

Comment: it can work on every ajax call, so that's not a problem. THough if I use the global event like ajaxSuccess(), it's not going to fire after the success function of the ajax call itself

Comment: is there maybe a global event AFTER the success event that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use global events as such, it is called after all AJAX success callback:

```
$.ajaxSuccess(function(){
//do my global thing here
});
```

Perhaps ajaxSetup success callback is called at the same time? Didn't test

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    success: function() {
       // local within the ajaxSetup
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, but that won't fire AFTER the success function I have on the ajax call. it will fire simultaniously

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you bind the second function to first function

```
$.ajax().success(bla(new function() {
    //do whatever you want
}));
```

Here, `bla` takes a `function` as a parameter.

Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding you correctly, but as I mentioned, I am unable to touch the initial ajax request code. if I do it like you sugest, I'd have to rewrite my initial ajax success method, no?

Answer (score 0):

The

```
 complete: function(){
     // Handle the complete event
   }
```

fires after the success function and is the same as the global

```
ajaxComplete()
```